# Windows command line FOR loop match filename begining

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I am trying to archive event logs however, there are other event log files in the same folder so I cannot do *.evtx in the FOR loop.

Files are named: Archive-Security-2018-04-27-23-07-55-901.evtx

So I would like to match "Archive-Security" and archive them all.

Is there a way to match the beginning of the file?

this is what I have so far:

```
chdir /D "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\111"
FOR %%i IN (*.evtx) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i"
```

Comment: `FOR %%i IN (Archive-Security*.evtx)`, and why don't just add all of them to the same *.7z file? it'll be faster and produce smaller output

Comment: I tried that and doesnt seem to work. Will try it again.

Comment: ok started working  :) now... how do i mark as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match only files beginning with `Archive-Security` use `Archive-Security*.evtx`. That'll work with any commands that accept a wildcard

```
FOR %%i IN (Archive-Security*.evtx) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~ni.7z" "%%i"
```